# Specify the default initial value for check boxes

Tags: r, shiny

In the following code, there are check boxes. I want to force so that the first check box is checked as an initial default values.

[image]

**The Answer of @Stéphane Laurent**

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  uiOutput("checkbox_GUI_Readers"),
  textOutput("xxx"),

  textOutput("txt_user_specifies_reader_IDs")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {


  output$checkbox_GUI_Readers <- renderUI({
    checkboxGroupInput("R_object_as_the_result_of_check_boxes_for_reader", "Select Reader ID", choices =  seq(1:8 ),
                       select =1 # This specify the initial condition
                       )
  })



  output$txt_user_specifies_reader_IDs <- renderText({
    icons <- paste(input$R_object_as_the_result_of_check_boxes_for_reader, collapse = ", ")
    paste("Select reader IDs:", icons)
  })

  output$xxx <- renderText({
    icons <- input$R_object_as_the_result_of_check_boxes_for_reader 
    paste( str (icons))
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Try `selected = "1"` in `checkboxGroupInput`.

Comment: Thank you, it goes through.